# SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<' 1

Tags: html, angularjs

I have tried all the solutions given for the same question. But the error is still been displayed.
The code below is from index.html where the all the dependencies are linked.The path to all the files have been checked.

```
<base href="/">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:200,400,500,700,400italic">-->
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.4/angular-material.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs.css'>
<!--for icons-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.css">

<!--for general-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js "></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-aria.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-messages.min.js "></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.js "></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular-ui-router@1.0.0-alpha.4/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

<!--for md-data-table -->
<script src="https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
<!--for home-->
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-resource.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.min.js'></script>
<!---->
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.link/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.1.4/angular-material.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs.css'>

<!--for data table-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table/master/dist/md-data-table.css">

<script src='https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/svg-assets-cache.js'>
</script>

<!-- components and services   -->
<script src="/client/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app.js"></script>
<script src="/components/login.js"></script>
<script src="/components/signup.js"></script>
<script src="/components/signup2.js"></script>    
<script src="/components/page2.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page3.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page4.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page5.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page6.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page7.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page8.js"></script>
<script src="/components/page9.js"></script>
<script src="/components/dashboard.js"></script>
<script src="/client/js/loginService.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/js/lf-ng-md-file-input.js"></script>

<script src="/components/doctor_restricted.js"></script>


<!-- Visualizer and url -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!--for input file type-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/css/lf-ng-md-file-input.min.css">

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/d3@3"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/ui-router-visualizer@1"></script>
```

[image: error displayed in the console:]

js code for which the error is been displayed- loginService:

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('app',[])
    .factory('loginService', Service);

function Service($http,$state,$window, $log) {
    var service = {};
    service.demo = function(){
        console.log('hello from service');
    };
    return service;
}
 })();
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressJwt = require('express-jwt');
const path = require('path')
const cred = require('./server/config/cred');

// Basic usage
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/orola');
console.log(cred.jwtSecret);
app.use('/secure', expressJwt({secret: cred.jwtSecret}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client'));

require('./server/routes/doctor')(app);
require('./server/routes/user')(app);

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('./client/index.html'));
});

app.listen(3003, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

Comment: Browse to `/client/app.js`. I'm pretty sure your server is sending some HTML error and not the actual JS content. You can just click on the app.js link on the error list.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please try to reduce your question to a MWE (minimal working example) or check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .  People are unlikely to read so much code but if you can reproduce the error with just ~10 lines, I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen yes, it opens index.html with <html> marked in red. Could you please tell why is this happening and what should be done to correct it?

Comment: I would assume the route you set up to return index.html for any request might have something to do with it.